# Chrome and Firefox not passing querystring value with jquery load()

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

While working with some jQuery ajax, I've run into this problem with Chrome and Firefox not passing a 
 querystring value with jquery load()

Here is the markup:

```
<a href="#" class="abort-invitation" id='abort-invitation-103'>abort</a>
```

The jquery script:

```
$('a.abort-invitation').live(
  {
     click: function (e) {
     var $link = $(this);
     var querystringValue = $link.html();
     var randomnumber = new Date().getTime();
     var urlPath = '<%:Url.Action("AbortInvitation", "Evaluation") %>' + '?
                  inviteState=' + querystringValue + '&ran=' + randomnumber; 
     var $modal = GetModal();
     $modal.load(urlPath);
    // more javascript ...
```

The MVC method being called on load():

```
public PartialViewResult AbortInvitation()
{
  ViewData["inviteState"] = Request.QueryString["inviteState"];
  var randomValue = Request.QueryString["ran"];
  return PartialView("~/views/evaluation/controls/AbortOrReactivate.ascx");
}
```

While debugging in Visual Studio ViewData["inviteState"] will give me a value when load
is fired from IE(8), and in Chrome(16.0) and FireFox(8) I will get "" as the passed in value. Does anyone have a clue or a solution for why one browser works as expected, and the other two fail at passing the querystring value?

(Note: most of the vars are just my attempt at trying to isolate the problem and break things down one at a time. The random number is attached in case there is some caching going on. We only really care about the var 'querystringValue' itself.)

Comment: Does the `querystringValue` variable have a value if you debug in chrome?

Comment: I actually tried watching the request post through firebug and saw that the values for the querystrings were empty, yet if I pop a javascript alert box with the ulrPath variable I can see that the string has been created successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try properly url encoding your request parameters:

```
var urlPath = '<%: Url.Action("AbortInvitation", "Evaluation") %>';
var $modal = GetModal();
$modal.load(urlPath, {
    inviteState: querystringValue,
    ran: randomnumber
});
```

Also jQuery has a built-in mechanism for disabling the cache, so this `ran` variable seems not necessary:

```
var urlPath = '<%: Url.Action("AbortInvitation", "Evaluation") %>';
$.ajax({
    url: urlPath,
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    data: { inviteState: querystringValue },
    success: function(result) {
        var $modal = GetModal();
        $modal.html(result);
    } 
});
```

Comment: I agree about the ran variable. I don't think it has anything to do with the actual posting of the querystring. I will try the proper encoding of the querystring values like you have given and see if the values are getting passed at that time. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris, no, probably it doesn't. You just have to ensure that you are properly url encoding your request parameters.

Comment: While I attempted to get the url encoding working, I actually decided that the entire chunk of code wasn't as clear as it could have been. I decided to go a different direction and did the logic on the client side which avoids the need of passing a querystring value to the server. Thanks for the help though.